# I want to get the column name or index from this excel sheet

Tags: excel

[Screenshot of Excel Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCSXk.png)

My data is like the above image I want a formula or any other way so I can get the column name or index no of the right answer after comparing the Option 1,2,3 column with the Answer column of every row in the excel sheet. Please help me.

Comment: (a) Excel isn't a database. (b) [A CSV text dump or Markdown table would be much better than a screenshot](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577).

Answer (score 0):

I got a way to do this after searching many web pages. Here's what I do.

1.Make a new column with the name of Index a. where I will store the value of my comparison. First I compare option 1 with the answer column with this formula: =IF(EXACT(A2,B2),"a"," "). In A2 I put the column of option 1 and in B2 I put the value of Answer column then in true value I put a and in false I leave it blank as I need only a, b, and c as my final result.
2. Do the same for option 2 and  option 3.
3. Then I merged the values of Index 1, Index 2 and Index 3 into one column using this formula: =CONCATENATE(A1,B1,C1).

Hope it will help others. If you know any shortway don't forget to share it.

Comment: I save typing, instead of " CONCATENATE(A1,B1,C1) ", I use "=A1&B1&C1"